# Dynamic Link in Libs Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

working on a C++ for mobile project in MSVS 2019, I am trying to get .so (shared object) file added to the project via the .vcxproj XML and switch versions of the library that are included dynamically based on selected VS configuration in the IDE.

I played around with it for a while but cannot get exactly as described above.

Anyone had experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: i'm more than sure there're special commands that can be placed to `.h` file or whatever you have that does it. like there https://github.com/alexeyneu/tool3/blob/57a66dcd3fc3649951521aa80147441c7e04e45b/tool3/stdafx.h#L35    .  to add it to `.apk` . `.so` nothing to do in a project

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for the comment, it is a .so lib from the Oculus SDK so i didnt compile it, just trying to add to C++ for mobile development project for Android. Thanks

Comment: @Алексей Неудачин thanks for the comment, ah yeah forgot about this alternative method, will try it. Cheers

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин thanks but no the clang compiler just shits itself again unless lib file directly added to solution.

Comment: add it to project and check cmd line changes then do thing i told

Comment: Got it working: added ItemGroup to the project .vcxitems xml containing the libs and it is fine now.